# Eventbrite - Pre-populate invited delegate properties

Tags: eventbrite

I am proposing a solution for a charity and they want to be able to manage conference attendees. I would like to recommend they use Eventbrite for this, but one of their requirements is to store other pieces of attendee information in the form.  I know I can upload a list of delegates for them to invite (it will be a privite, invite only event) but can I also pass more information such as their contact details, a club they are a member of, etc so that it is visible in Eventbrite for the conference organisers?

If so, could you point me to some documentation that details how this is done?

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Eventbrite doesn't allow event organizers to pass in these variables through an API.

We have a way that an event organizer could choose to collect this information from the user when they are registering: http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/426127-custom-questions-for-attendees

Additionally, if the event organizer wants to add attendees manually, then they can do this through an Admin webform here: http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/428370-add-attendees-manually

Unfortunately though, we don't allow event organizers to bulk upload attendee lists and leverage Eventbrite tools without the attendees going through the registration.

Cheers!
Mitch